# Disprove: There exist unique integers $q$ and $r$ such that $204=25q+r$.

Tags: proof-writing, divisibility

Disprove:

There exist unique integers $q$ and $r$ such that $204=25q+r$.

I need to use the division algorithm somehow, but I don't see how I can disprove it when it seems to be true.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Edit: It must follow that $0\le{r}<25$.

Comment: Do you require $0 \le r \lt 25$?

Comment: You missed the word "unique".  You can disprove that by showing there is no solution *or* by showing there is more than one.  In this case there is more than one.

Comment: You can pick any integer value you like for $q$ and solve for $r$. In this way you can generate zillions of different solutions. Two different solutions would be enough to disprove uniqueness.

Comment: Probably you want $\ 0 \le |r| < 25\ $ so the two possible remainders are $\, 204\equiv r\equiv 4\equiv -21\pmod{25}\ $

Answer (score 1):

Consider $q=8，r=4$, and $q=9, r=-21$

Answer (score 0):

There are no restrictions on $q$ and $r$. We first find one such pair by the division algorithm:
$$204=25\cdot8+4\qquad q,r=8,4$$
Now add one to the quotient, and subtract 25 from the remainder to compensate, completing the disproof:
$$204=25\cdot9-21\qquad q,r=9,-21$$